# Converting to Pandas MultiIndex

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe of the form:

```
     SpeciesName    0
0        A          [[Year: 1, Quantity: 2],[Year: 3, Quantity: 4...]]
1        B          [[Year: 1, Quantity: 7],[Year: 2, Quantity: 15...]]
2        C          [[Year: 2, Quantity: 9],[Year: 4, Quantity: 13...]]
```

I'm attempting to try and create a MultiIndex that uses the SpeciesName and the year as the index:

```
SpeciesName  Year 
     A        1   Data
              2   Data
     B        1   Data
              2   Data
```

I have not been able to get pandas.MultiIndex(..) to work and my attempts at iterating through the dataset and manually creating a new object have not been very fruitful. Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How do you want this `Data` to look once you've reshaped? Where do the `Year` values come from? Sorry, this is a bit unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume your data is list of dictionaries... because if I don't, what you've written makes no sense unless they are strings and I don't want to parse strings

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['A', [dict(Year=1, Quantity=2), dict(Year=3, Quantity=4)]],
    ['B', [dict(Year=1, Quantity=7), dict(Year=2, Quantity=15)]],
    ['C', [dict(Year=2, Quantity=9), dict(Year=4, Quantity=13)]]
], columns=['SpeciesName', 0])

df

  SpeciesName                                                          0
0           A   [{'Year': 1, 'Quantity': 2}, {'Year': 3, 'Quantity': 4}]
1           B  [{'Year': 1, 'Quantity': 7}, {'Year': 2, 'Quantity': 15}]
2           C  [{'Year': 2, 'Quantity': 9}, {'Year': 4, 'Quantity': 13}]
```

---

Then the solution is **obvious**

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    *zip(*(
        [d, s]
        for s, l in zip(
            df['SpeciesName'], df[0].values.tolist())
        for d in l
    ))
).set_index('Year', append=True)

        Quantity
  Year          
A 1            2
  3            4
B 1            7
  2           15
C 2            9
  4           13
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. It's not quite what I needed but the zip idea was really useful and I had totally overlooked the append setting in set_index. Given how confusing my question was asked I'm surprised you were able to decipher it. I'll be sure to post better explanations!